# php merge multiple array elements remain the same, an array of different elements

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

Help:

Array format like this:

```
    $arr=array(
        array('element1'=>'a','element2'=>1),
        array('element1'=>'b','element2'=>2),
        array('element1'=>'a','element2'=>2),
        array('element1'=>'b','element2'=>3),
        );
```

Synthesis is needed,how to change it like:

```
$arr=array(
    array('element1'=>'a','element2'=>array(1,2)),
    array('element1'=>'b','element2'=>array(2,3)),
    );
```

Comment: What attempts have you made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$new = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $new[$value['element1']][] = $value['element2'];
}
$new2 = array();
foreach($new as $k=>$v){
    $new2[] = array('element1'=>$k,'element2'=>$v);
}
print_r($new2);
```

### Result

```
array(
    array('element1' => 'a', 'element2' => array(0 => 1, 1 => 2)),
    array('element1' => 'b', 'element2' => array(0 => 2, 1 => 3)),
   )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I need to look carefully to understand your ideas, I will handle myself once again, thank you again!